# bcryptjs not logging in, but I can register a user

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

I am a Nodejs newbie, I have created a simple login/register API. I am using bcryptjs for my passwords. I am testing my API on postman, I am able to register a new user. when I login with a wrong email, I get the correct message. My issue is when I try to login with the correct email/password I do not get any response. here is my code

```
const express = require("express")
const users = express.Router()
const cors = require('cors')
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken")
const bcrypt =require('bcryptjs')
const User = require("../models/User")
users.use(cors())

process.env.SECRET_KEY ='secret'

users.post('/register',(req, res)=>{
    const today  = new Date()
    const userData={
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        email: req.body.email,
        mobile_no: req.body.mobile_no,
        created: today,
        active: req.body.active,
        password: req.body.password
    }
    User.findOne({
        where:{
            email: req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user =>{
        if(!user){
            bcrypt.hash(req.body.password,10,(err, hash) =>{
                userData.password =hash
                User.create(userData)
                .then(user =>{
                    res.json({status: user.email + ' registered'})
                })
                .catch(err =>{
                    res.send('error:' + err)
                })
            })
        }else {
            res.json({error: " User already exists"})
        }
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.send('error:'+ err)
    })
})

users.post('/login',(req, res)=>{
    User.findOne({
        where:{
            email:req.body.email
        }
    })
    .then(user =>{
        if(user){
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
                let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
                    expiresIn: 10000
                })
                res.send(token)
            }
        }else{
            res.status(400).json({error: ' User does not Exist'})

        }
    })
    .catch(err =>{
        res.status(400).json({error: err})
    })
})
module.exports = users;
```

Please HELP!

Comment: Since I don't know how do you pass req.body.password it's kinda hard for me to help you out.

Comment: Can you please `console.log(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY)` and show us the value

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are not using the bcryptjs properly. While login your password hash you are giving user.password, I think there is a mistake.

```
To hash a password:

var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
var salt = bcrypt.genSaltSync(10);
var hash = bcrypt.hashSync("B4c0/\/", salt);
// Store hash in your password DB.
To check a password:

// Load hash from your password DB.
bcrypt.compareSync("B4c0/\/", hash);  
bcrypt.compareSync("not_bacon", hash);
```

Comment: I am able to save a hashed password; I am a newbie but i believe the problem is here >> `        if(user){
            if(bcrypt.compareSync(req.body.password, user.password)){
                let token = jwt.sign(user.dataValues, process.env.SECRET_KEY,{
                    expiresIn: 10000
                })
                res.send(token)
            }
        `